# Mapped drive accessible from my computer but not "Browse" window

Tags: windows, networking, permissions

I have **mapped a network drive** on a Windows 7 enterprise 32 bit computer successfully and it is **accessible when accessing it through "My Computer"**.

When I open a program and attempt to **browse to said mapped network drive**, windows **prompts me for a password** (It has remembered the username). If I type the password and check the "Remember login" checkbox, after a restart Windows asks again.

If I right click on the drive from within the **browse window** and go to properties it tells me the drive is **disconnected**. If I do the same thing from **My Computer** the drive is **connected**.

In task manager, the process for the browse window that cannot access the drive is using the standard **logged in user account**, e.g. Max.

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: It's a coading/programming forum !

Answer (score 1):

The account from which you are trying, is it an adminstrator account ? If not, then try running the program using 'Run as administrator'.

Comment: Yes it is an admin account and the program is being ran as admin.